# Unable to do search for selected items

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am using this code to search for selected items inside a checkbox list and it doesn't work.

```
protected void btnSearchCode_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValues = string.Empty;
    foreach (ListItem item in cblCode.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
            selectedValues += item.Value + ",";
    }
    if (selectedValues != string.Empty)
        selectedValues = selectedValues.Remove(selectedValues.Length - 1);
    cblCode.DataSource = DataReport.SearchCode(selectedValues);
    cblCode.DataBind();
} 

 public static DataTable SearchCode(string selectedValues)
    {
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalDB"].ConnectionString;
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            string strQuery = "Select Group, Name from Details where Code in (" + selectedValues + ")", conn;
            command.Connection = conn;
            SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dataadapter.SelectCommand = command;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataadapter.Fill(datatable);
        }
        return datatable;
    }
```

Really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? Do you get an error or simply no results?

Comment: I get this erroe when I hit search. Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: What is the value of `strcon` variable?

Comment: string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalDB"].ConnectionString;

Comment: No, the value itself. Just trying to rule out possibility that connection is not being retrieved from config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the query string but you never assign it to the `command` variable. Therefore, when you assign it to `selectCommand`, there isn't anything to query from DB. You want to add this line of code to assign the query string to variable:
`command = new SqlCommand(strQuery,conn);`

Answer (score 1):

You have not used strQuery at all.

Try this :

```
public static DataTable SearchCode(string selectedValues)
      {
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalDB"].ConnectionString;
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strcon))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string strQuery = "Select Group, Name from Details where Code in (" + selectedValues + ")";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dataadapter.SelectCommand = command;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dataadapter.Fill(datatable);
        }
        return datatable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Always Use `SqlParamerter` while passing parameters to the database

i think You are missing single inverted comma because Your SeletedValues is `string`

```
string strQuery = "Select Group, Name from Details 
where Code in ('" + selectedValues + "')", conn;
```

Comment: That won't work. If it's a list of strings, you need the single quotes around each string.

Comment: i think it will be better if he uses string like this "1,3,5,7" than
"a,g,b,h"

Comment: Not sure I understand you, but here goes. If his checklist has values 1,2,3,4 then `selectedValues` = "1,2,3,4" and he can directly pass it in as `where Code in ('" + selectedValues + "')"`. But if the checklist has values "abc","def","pqr","xyz", then he needs to construct `selectedValues` itself as "'abc','def','pqr','xyz'". Either way, the single quotes do not need to be there.

Comment: @shree.pat18 yes exactly